# Unknown device showing up in network scan

Tags: networking, wireshark, nmap, device

I need some help finding a device that has been showing up whenever I scan my network using Spiceworks' "Inventory" scan.

I can `ping` the device, but `nslookup` returns a non-existent domain, and Spiceworks is telling me that the device has no open ports. Opening a browser window and pointing it at the IP returns nothing (expected). I'm not familiar enough with Wireshark to be able to wield it well, and of course in order to remotely scan the Unknown Device I need some kind of daemon on it in the first place. Tough to do when you don't know where or what it is. Nmap simply says there are no ports open on the device.

I know for sure the device has a static IP, and it is most likely a wired device. Our switches are on the old side, and the few I've figured out how to access (the rest seem to be using very outdated passwords that no one knows) don't have a MAC scanning feature (that I've seen).

Could use some help. Is there a tool out there that could tell me which port in which switch a device is connected to? I'd like to find the physical location of this device.

Comment: What does your network look like? Is it a SOHO, or a commercial grade device?

Comment: Commercial. Still working on getting model numbers and all that for the inventory, but one of 'em that i have access to is a NetGear FS728TP, if that's any help. Other switches are similar. Few Cisco, couple NetGear, etc.

Comment: Did nmap attempt to identify the manufacturer?  does the arp table show the MAC address?

Comment: nmap did attempt, and came back with "Billionton Systems". Unfamiliar to me. I did snag the MAC address from it, though.

EDIT: nmap can't detect the OS, though. "Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details".

Comment: They appear to make wireless adapters and suchlike; maybe it's a USB adapter. And it's borderline whether a FS728TP is a commercial grade device.

Comment: Looked to me like the manufacturer made mostly microcontrollers or something along those lines... Didn't see anything about USB adapters specifically, but I'll definitely scour the server room for something like that.

Comment: If you are on (or have access to) a host on the same network look at the arp table to get the MAC of the device and then search for it's manufacture, should at least give you a clue to what it is.

Comment: This might be my ignorance towards arp speaking, but it doesn't look like it's giving me any information that nmap didn't give.